# Maximum of the probability mass function of the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analysis, statistics, probability-distributions

What is the maximum of the probability mass function of the binomial distribution (not depending of number of trials, the unique variable being the probability)?

Some work and explanation:
$$\max f(p)= \max Pr(X=  np )= \lim_{n \to \infty} \binom{n}{\lceil np \rceil} \cdot p^{np}(1-p)^{n-np}$$,

where, $p$ is the probability, $n$ is the number of trials, $f$ is the probability mass function, for $np$ a integer (mean=mode=np when this condition happens).

It seems very intuitive that this number exist and is well defined if we think $p=1/2$, for it is the (or mean of the two) central number(s) of the $n$  line of the pascal triangle divided by $2^n$.

I have tried approximate it by the normal distribution, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of the binomial density is of size $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ times a constant depending on $p$, as $n\to\infty$. The calculation is straightforward but unenlightening using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). A more intuitive way to see where the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ scaling comes from is the Central Limit Theorem, which says that as $n\to\infty$ the binomial density is well-approximated by a normal distribution with mean $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, which means that there will be a constant multiple of $\sqrt{n}$ values with a non-negligible contribution to the distribution, while will all have roughly constant relative density. Since the sum of these $\sqrt{n}$ values is very close to $1$, and the smallest is within a constant multiple of the largest, that means the largest is a constant times $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. (Again, all constants depend on $p$, and I am assuming $p$ is held fixed in $(0,1)$ as $n\to\infty$, or if $p$ is allowed to vary then it is converging to a value in $(0,1)$ at the very least.)